# zookeeper unit test：quorumPeer never got set

Tags: unit-testing, apache-zookeeper

I want to write zookeeper unit test, use embedded zookeeper curator-test.
When my zookeeper version is less than 3.4.0, like 3.3.0, there is no problem.
But when I use the following configuration, there will be problems.
I have searched for many ways to try to solve, but the problem still exists.

**maven pom dependencies:**

```
<!--zookeeper-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-recipes</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>curator-client</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

> my unit test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TestingCluster cluster = new TestingCluster(3);
    cluster.start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    TestingZooKeeperServer leader = null;
    for(TestingZooKeeperServer zs : cluster.getServers()){
        System.out.print(zs.getInstanceSpec().getServerId()+"-");
        System.out.print(zs.getQuorumPeer().getServerState()+"-");
        System.out.println(zs.getInstanceSpec().getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        if( zs.getQuorumPeer().getServerState().equals( "leading" )){
            leader = zs;
        }
    }
    leader.kill();
    System.out.println( "--After leader kill:" );
    for(TestingZooKeeperServer zs : cluster.getServers()){
        System.out.print(zs.getInstanceSpec().getServerId()+"-");
        System.out.print(zs.getQuorumPeer().getServerState()+"-");
        System.out.println(zs.getInstanceSpec().getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    }
    cluster.stop();
}
```

error & Exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: configFileStr
at org.apache.curator.test.QuorumConfigBuilder$1.<init>(QuorumConfigBuilder.java:142)
at org.apache.curator.test.QuorumConfigBuilder.buildConfig(QuorumConfigBuilder.java:137)
at org.apache.curator.test.TestingZooKeeperServer$1.run(TestingZooKeeperServer.java:157)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: quorumPeer never got set
    at org.apache.curator.test.TestingQuorumPeerMain.blockUntilStarted(TestingQuorumPeerMain.java:90)
    at org.apache.curator.test.TestingZooKeeperServer.start(TestingZooKeeperServer.java:167)
    at org.apache.curator.test.TestingCluster.start(TestingCluster.java:149)
```

I have try:
[removing extra zookeeper dependency](https://github.com/charithe/kafka-junit/issues/22)
[version control](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CURATOR-428)
But this problem is still not solved, I hope a master can help me point out, thx!!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/apache/curator/blob/master/curator-test-zk34/README.md
OMG, I'm so stupid that I didn't expect this to happen

Comment: What was the issue you faced? The link in your comment is no longer valid! :(